# object detection using tensorflow by own classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

When I try training my train.py for object detection using the tensorflow/models repository using the code

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training_dir/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_pets.config
```

I am unable to run this command.

I have tried including all the files within object_detection as well tried to remove the object_detection. In the from statement, but it didn't work.

```
import functools
import json
import os
import tensorflow as tf

from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
from object_detection.builders import graph_rewriter_builder
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.legacy import trainer
from object_detection.utils import config_util
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/varsh/Documents/models/research/object_detection/train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem in my system (windows 10). The solution is not very straight forward but:

1) First u need to clone Tensorflow Object Detection API repository https://github.com/tensorflow/models.

2) Follow the installation provided in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

3) In the step 2, you are required to compile protobuf library, so download the protobuf compiler at https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/latest (at the time of this writing (3.5.1), there's a bug in protoc which may or may not related to the Windows environment, my solution is use the protoc v 3.4.0)
4) Append the PYTHONPATH environment variable with the directory of /research/ and /research/slim (dont forget to add the PYTHONPATH to Path if you haven't done so.

5) No more ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'